ExtJS 6.2.0: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
In ExtJS 6.2, this error appeared when I updated Chrome to version 131. Steps to reproduce this issue:

You need Chrome on Windows 10/11 : Version 131.0.6778.109 (current latest)
In Chrome go to chrome://accessibility/
Check the tick box to activate Web accessibility
Open this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1n7s&view/editor
Select version: Ext JS 6.2.1.167 - Classic
Try to just show or hide columns in the menu or just move the mouse on the column menu.

Is it possible to solve this?
Tried to update/downgrade Extjs - same problem.
In 6.5 it looks fine.

Are you saying it works in extjs 6.5? Why not just use that version? (why not just go to 6.7 then?)
